# Display NMAP topology in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, nmap, topology

In NMAP, I can view the output of an nmap scan in the graphical topology view. I have the python-nmap module and I was wondering if I could receive this information and display it in a tkinter window.

Is it possible to this?

If so how could I?

If not are there any workarounds or other ways to receive this data in graphical form?

I am using python 2 so any suggestions would be appreciated!

If you need any other info then please comment and I will respond.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You probably want to use the `canvas` widget. For an example, see [here](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_canvas.php) or [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html).

Comment: how do I use this to access NMAP's topology?